# how to close dialog in jQuery automatically on some condition

Tags: jquery

I have some group of check box of which user has to select atleast one and proceed further activity.
when the user clicks on a button i check the above functionality if the user has selected one than allow to open a dialog else alert the user to select minimum one and don't open the Dialog.

following is the function to open a dialog.

```
function openLoadInfo(){
    global.getElementById("diaLoad").value="";
    global.getElementById("diaReadydate").value="";
    global.getElementById("diaCanceldate").value="";

      $("#loadinfo")
        .dialog(
                {
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    title: "Load # info",
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 300,
                    // open: function() {
                    //            
                    // },
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function () {
                           $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
```

through the following script i am able to get value if check box is selected .

```
$('input:checked').each(function() {
          alert("Value : "+$(this).val());
        });
```

if the above code fails than i have to close the dialog and prompt the user to select at least one check box.

Please help me to get this.

Regards

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now in your case you can write in jQuery

```
$('input checked').live('click',function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                diolag.open();
            }
            else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
                alert("please select mimimum one")
            }

});
```

Comment: User can select multiple check box, least condition is at least one one should be selected other wise user can select N number of check box

Comment: LOL @AbhijitPandya.` a man requir that user can select only one checkbox` what do you mean by this ??

Comment: so dont give a same name to all chaeckboxes. it is not necessary. if u want to apply this on perticular checkbox then give Id to that checkbox or this is for all checkboxes..

Answer (score 2):

```
((yourCondition) ? $(this).dialog( "close" );  $(this).dialog("destroy"); : '');
```